# LMMS 1.0.2 Midi recording noise

Tags: ubuntu-studio, audio-recording, lmms

As shown [in this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFVk70yoo6g), the MIDI works well before recording. After recording, there is noise.

How do I fix this?

Comment: sounds like clipping... you might have volume too high for the recording.

Comment: @Matreo where do I do this? LMMS has no volume control for recordings, and the system audio settings for recording only show when I use audacity to record from mic.

Answer (score 1):

What you're hearing is clipping, this occurs when the waveform changes sharply or suddenly, to a value more than the audio's maximum tolerance. It occurs most commonly in LMMS when a waveform is cut wrongly, which is likely what is happening here.

My first instinctive solution is to lower the instrument's volume, so your note isn't as likely to hit the audio 'ceiling'.

If that doesn't work, and your sound doesn't clip while playing, my personal best solution is to edit the instrument properties so that the envelope has a sustain / release value to it. This will lower the volume quickly instead of simply cutting off the note.

There are also other tools out there such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) that have features/plugins to help remove clipping. If you're OK with it during production, you could simply go back over your exported sound and edit it.

If your instrument is always doing this, you should take a look at the MIDI velocity the notes are coming in at. It may be a bit too high for many instruments not to clip.

Answer (score 0):

Open Instrument settings, by clicking on the Instruments name in the song editor.

When the Instrument settings window opens, go to the second tab. (You can change the tabs by using the bar that shows multiple icons like the midi icon or the fx icon.)

Then when you are on the second tab, make sure that volume is selected(and not cutoff or reso)

Then put the AMT (to the right of the envelope box) to maximum.

Leave DEL at zero. Put ATT to somewhere around 0.05 and 0.1.

Leave HOLD and DEC at default value.

Put SUST to maximum, and REL also somewhere around 0.05 and 0.1

If you want to have a sustain like effect, you could also put REL to a higher value